# How to catch a keyboard event without overriding the implement method keyDown for NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, keydown, appkit

I have implemented a custom class MyTableView that inherits from NSTableView.
I then added two of this custom table view in my .xib file. 
What I would like to do is just navigating through both tables using arrow keys (left and right). The selected row would just simply go from one table to another (I don't know if I'm clear)

Instead of overriding the KeyDown method that would make me reimplement everything (I think being lazy is a good habit in programming :) ), I would just like to say after the classic keyDown method have been called, "Hey, if the key pressed is left or right arrow, change of table view and select me the appropriate row).

I have a MyTableViewController that controls the MyTableView class. Can I just catch keyDown event in this class and deal with these events (again without changing the KeyDown method in MyTableView)?

Generally speaking, is there a way to inherit from a method without writing everything again? Like the classes? You do not have to recreate all the class's behaviour with heritage, that would be super cool to do so with methods.

Comment: The phrase "that would make me reimplement everything" makes me think you don't understand you can call the base class method if you aren't interested in the key.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you, it is so obvious to me now haha

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by making a menu with left-arrow key. I believe this is actually a recommended way to make a key-command because this will make the command visible to users. Here's an example.

```
SEL         s1  =   NSSelectorFromString(@"test1:");    
unichar     c1  =   NSLeftArrowFunctionKey;
NSMenuItem* m4  =   [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test 1" action:s1 keyEquivalent:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c1 length:1]];

[m4 setKeyEquivalentModifierMask:0];  // Remove need for command key.
```

Add this menu to the main menu.

Comment: Thank you for this proposal, however I think the way I implemented it will be natural for users so I won't have to create a menu item that will add stuff to my menu. I want to keep it very simple.